# Research topic for optimisation

Tags: optimization, soft-question

I am an undergraduate student in computer science with a strong inclination towards mathematics. I want to do some research work under my mathematics Professor who specialises in Optimisation related techniques. So, I want to ask what are some research topics in optimisation with which I can approach my professor?
I want some topics on which I can work upon without prior deep knowledge about them. I will grateful for your help.

Comment: Why not just ask your professor?

Comment: Is there any other field that interests you that might *use* optimization as a technique (physics, computer science, statistics, environmental science, neuroscience, ...)?

Comment: Start with Maxima/minima in calculus, calculus of variations where object function and constraint function are learnt among others.

Answer (score 1):

Operations research is one suggestion. I would investigate the possible applications and pick one you have an interest in or a passion for. An interesting and useful hot topic would be to research the current US healthcare system.